# SearchResultsUpdating not updating

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, io

Ok so I have a `UITableViewController` and created a `SearchViewController` to search through an array of investments I made. The investments display in the `UITableView` (by alphabetical order), but when I click search and type in some letters, there in no updating to show investments with those letters.

I feel like this is a simple mistake I made and it would really help if I could get some tips and help.

Here are a couple images of the code I have right now.  (Sorry if I included some unnecessary code)

[image]

and also this one:

[image]

Thanks guys and hope that it can be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i would recommend you to do is to implement the UISearchBarDelegate methods an there you can do search by word or when user types the search on the keyboard where you should filter the dataSource and then reset the tableview data (this will update your table with the new data the user is searching for)

In your implementation you did not added

```
searchbar.delegate = self
```

so the search doesn't know you are searching

EDIT: to implement UISearchBarDelegate to as follows

```
class NewTableViewController: UITableViewController {

 ovveride viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    searchbar.delegate = self
     }
 }

extension NewTableViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
        search()
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
         search()
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    search()
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
       search()
}

func searchBarResultsListButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
       search()
}
}
```

Comment: I think this would work but where should I put it under, my viewdidload? or..? thanks @John

Comment: the delegate you put it inside viewDidLoad and for the rest you create an extension to your class that implements UISearchBarDelegate... I updated my comment with the delegate where the search() represents your search functionality if you want to use that method

Comment: also don't forget to approve if this solved your problem so other users who have a related problem can find the solution as well